# Another word to say “ Such as ”

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to use the word “say” instead of “such as” in a sentence, just like the following?

> Air pollution causes a lot of health problems, say, cancer and vision issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it's very informal. I think it's short for *say for example* and *for example* or *e.g.* would probably be better substitutions.

The informality of *say* makes you sound less sure as well, like you're suggesting some ideas instead of listing examples of health problems you *know* are caused by pollution. I don't think that's the tone you're going for, so I'd use more assertive phrases like *such as*, *for example*, or *like* if you want to be a little less formal.

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence would start out formally grammatically as:

> Air pollution causes a lot of health problems *such as* cancer and vision issues.

You could also say

> Air pollution causes a lot of health problems *like* cancer and vision issues.

For what you're using it as, ['say' is an adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/say), short for "let's say", a parenthetical aside. That is, it can be removed without changing any thing else. It is not exactly a perfect meaning-preserving replacement for 'such as' or 'like'. But it could be replaced with "for example".

Though 'say' in this context has the same bland primary meaning as 'for example', namely "Here are some examples", it has this colloquial feeling of "I'm just pulling this example out of thin air out of many and there's no special reason I'm picking it but it's the only one I can think of". That is, there's a bit of doubt how representative the example really is when you use 'say'.

> Air pollution causes a lot of health problems *like* cancer and vision issues.

> Air pollution causes a lot of health problems *like*, **say**, cancer and vision issues.

> Air pollution causes a lot of health problems *like*, **for example**, cancer and vision issues.

For these last two examples, the 'say' or 'for example' are slightly redundant, and probably for good style should be left out. 'like' introduces the examples just fine.

You might hear (or read):

> Air pollution causes a lot of health problems, *say,* cancer and vision issues.

and it sounds unremarkable in regular speech, and might be overlooked in most print, but a good news/newspaper editor or teacher would notice it as a bit less than formal and consider the "cancer and vision issues" as an attempt at a sentence with no verb.

As usual, check with your teacher; you'll want to follow their examples to ensure you get points.

Comment: I had a very difficult time (in the sense that I couldn't) finding examples of adverbial 'say' at [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22%2C+say%2C%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: I think a lack of examples at Google NGram viewer is a testament to just how informal it is. The way I use it is almost always to introduce a specific thing as a substitute for talking about a large class of things. For example, “Let’s look at pollution caused health issues, say asthma, and how the cost of treatment compares with...”  I would be less likely to use it in the given example, where the example issues are just examples and not going to be referred to again to make an additional point. That’s hard to explain well in a comment.

Comment: @ColleenV I thought it was more of a problem with the search interface, that 'say' is a -very- common word, but the adverbial use here is very much (comparatively) rarer. I tried to use commas around 'say' since that is often how it is written, but that just messes with the search syntax rather than getting what I want.

Comment: Without some sort of AI to look at the context, there are quite a few constructs that are nearly impossible to separate out from other usages

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. If you make that statement about air pollution, you presumably know most of the associated health problems and are just mentioning two as examples.

*Say* in this context means *let us say* and introduces some suggestions that you have just thought of.

> Why don't you paint your front door a bright colour - say, red or yellow?